# People clearly didnt read my post and jumped to judgement

Tags: support

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [General Data Protection Regulations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1006677/general-data-protection-regulations)

I asked a question, and its contained in the first paragraph, please not the question mark.
A appreciate you may not like it gelling with ubuntu's image but nonetheless it is valid.
What Will Cooke stated was unlawful under GDPR. He should know better. The fact alone he doesnt is in itself worrying. However my question remains and is entirely valid - how is it justified the nasty slurp of data checked by default under GDPR?

Comment: Your "question" isn't actually a question. You obviously didn't read the Help Center or How to Ask, because your "question" isn't an objective problem we can solve. You're just complaining about something.

Comment: Exactly like in your [ubuntu.se] post you don't ask a clear question but merely write a rant, and that's not tolerated neither there nor here. Come back when you're ready to express a real question, I suppose something like “Is the data collection enabled by default in 18.04 compatible with GDPR?” would match.

Comment: @dessert but I doubt it would be on topic here. Perhaps on [law.se] or some other site that deal with legal issues?

Answer (score 9):

This was the text of your question:

> How do you square this with GDPR , and that the data slurp is clearly unlawful? You would think Will Cooke would know better.Its a good thing I wouldnt touch Ubuntu with a bargepole let alone stick it anywhere near my hardware.

What's "this"? Who's Will Cooke? We don't work for Canonical here, why would you expect us to know the names of the people working for the company? When you ask a question, you need to give us enough context to understand what it is about. You came in as though continuing a conversation you were having with someone else.

I eventually looked up Will Cooke and figured out [what you were referring to](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/02/ubuntu-data-collection-opt-out) but still had absolutely no interest in answering you, because you came in here attacking. If you want to attack someone, go attack Canonical (if you really must), not a bunch of volunteers who freely give their time helping other users of an operating system. We don't build the thing, we just use it!

More importantly, even had you asked the question in a decent way, it would have been off topic here. I suggest you check our [Help Center](https://askubuntu.com/help) to understand what this site is about. We deal with technical issues about Ubuntu. If you have a gripe with Canonical (and many of us might share it), then you can take it somewhere where it is on topic.

So, in summary, you came in here with a confrontational attitude, without bothering to learn anything about what this site is or what its rules are, posted a "question" that isn't on topic in the first place, which gave no context, and which consisted of ~10% question and 90% attack. How else were you expecting to be treated?